# not understanding simple page

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to make sense of this tutorial

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax

I have a test page I am trying out

```
 @{
     Layout = null; 
  }

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html> 
     <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <title>Test</title> 
     </head> 
     <body>
      <div>
       Hello there
      </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

but when i run the page nothing appears

F12 shows this:

```
<html>

    <head></head>
    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong?

I'm trying this test project as well... same problem: https://github.com/sergiotapia/MicroShopping

Comment: How are you "running the page"?

Comment: What should be happen?

Comment: What _does_ happen though? How are you "running" this sample? Out of Visual Studio? Does a browser window open? ..

Comment: Trying removing the  @{ Layout = null;  }, and the page that are you updating is the index.cshtml or index.vbhtml or similar. The pages .html not are valid in the controller context

Comment: browser window opens
even when i remove the layout bit i still get a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the @{ Layout = null; }  part at the top, try removing that.  If you're looking to display a variable in the HTML section, that is where you would want to define that variable (at least that seems to be how they're doing it in the tutorial) like so:

```
@{ var myValue = "There"; }
```

and then calling that variable in the HTML section via

```
<div>
   Hello @myValue
</div>
```

Edit:
Another good habit to get into, as you learn, is to use the debugger (if you're using chrome, f12).  A lot of the time when something goes wrong, it will help you determine what it is that caused the problem.

Comment: The `Layout=null;` line stops a layout page being applied to the page, which might have been set in a _PageStart file, for instance.

Comment: The `Layout=null` is a perfectly valid statement and is useful in certain circumstances. It removes the "Master Page".

Answer (score 0):

If you created the page in WebMatrix, make sure you are "running" the right file. By default, if you just click *Run*, the `default.cshtml` file will launch in the browser. If you want to launch a different file, you can either right click on it in the file explorer and choose *Launch In Browser*, or make sure it is the current page in the Files Workspace and hit `Ctrl + F12`.

Comment: i did this. Im running from visual studio and i selected this page to be the start page

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that don't really match in your question, which leads me to think you hosted an ASP.NET MVC app inside a WebForms app. (I might be wrong). Also, I tested this myself in MVC4, and it worked perfectly without a problem.

In ASP.NET MVC, it is not possible to set a `.cshtml` file to be the default file. The reason for that is because the .cshtml file is only used inside a Controller to render a HTML View, not the other way around. This means a View can be used by more than one Controller. The default route can only be changed in the `RouteConfig.cs` file in the `~/App_Start` folder.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Is this what you did when you said you set your `.cshtml` file to be the default file ?

Comment: I have this as my default routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );